# How can I sent input to another program using python using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to send some inputs to a cmd based programme using python. The program takes normally type inputs from keyboard.

I tried as:

```
P1=subprocess.Popen("my_program",stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,sterr=subprocess.PIPE)
p1out,p1err=P1.communicate(input="my_input")
```

But gave error as "it requires byte like object not str". I had also tried with `P1.stdin.write()` method and gave same error again. What should be my input dtype?

Comment: you may need to pass arg `encoding='utf-8'` when you call `Popen`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using

```
my_input=my_input.encode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like all you have to change is your string to a 'bytes' type.

```
type("my_input")
>>>> str
type(b'my_input')
>>>> bytes
```